# Programmatically adding annotations

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.18, I had a python script that added annotations. I can't seem to get the annotations to add in 3.0:

```
for feature in iter:
            # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes
            # fetch geometry
            geom = feature.geometry()
            # show some information about the feature
            if geom.type() ==  0: #QgsWkbTypes.Point:
                print("In add annotation...")
                point = geom.asPoint()
                utmPoint = utm.from_latlon(point.y(), point.x())
                # fetch attributes
                attrs = feature.attributes()
                # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
                waypointText = attrs[0]
                textItem = QgsTextAnnotation (iface.mapCanvas())  
                crs = waypoint_layer.crs();
                document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
                document.setHtml("<strong>" + str(waypointText) + "</strong>")
                symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol()
                symbol.setSize(0);
                textItem.setDocument(document)
                textItem.setMapPosition(QgsPointXY(float(utmPoint[0]), float(utmPoint[1])))
                textItem.setMapLayer(waypoint_layer);
           #     textItem.setFrameSize(QSizeF(document.size().width() + 5,document.size().height() + 2))
           #     textItem.setFrameBorderWidth(2)
           #     textItem.setFrameColor(QColor("#e31a1c"))
           #     textItem.setFrameBackgroundColor(QColor("#d7d7d7"))
                 textItem.setMarkerSymbol(symbol)
           #     textItem.update()
```

Commented out textItem lines no longer work in 3.0, but even without setting frame specific features, the annotation doesn't show up.

Any examples of programatically adding an annotation to a map with QGIS 3.0?

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 5):

Add sample code for add annotations using **QGIS 3.0** , using point layer

```
layer = iface. activeLayer()
iter = layer.getFeatures()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

for feature in iter:
    # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes
    # fetch geometry
    geom = feature.geometry()
    # show some information about the feature
    if geom.type() ==  0: #QgsWkbTypes.Point:
        print("In add annotation...")
    point = geom.asPoint()
    # fetch attributes
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
    waypointText = attrs[0]
    html = "<strong>" + str(waypointText) + "</strong>"
    a = QgsTextAnnotation()
    c = QTextDocument()

    c.setHtml(html)
    a.setDocument(c)

    a.setFrameSize(QSizeF(100, 50))
    a.setMapLayer(layer)
    a.setFrameOffsetFromReferencePoint(QtCore.QPointF(30, 30))
    a.setMapPosition(point)
    a.setMapPositionCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs()))

    i = QgsMapCanvasAnnotationItem(a, canvas)
```

And the result is

[image]
**Tested using QGIS 3.6.2**

Comment: It's also good to use `QgsAnnotationManager` to manage the annotations.

`QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(a)`
`QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().removeAnnotation(a)`

Comment: How can I please prevent points from turning red? I have two different layers where I add annotations, but after that all points turn red.