# Rendering CSV file as annotation on QgsMapCanvas

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, csv, vector-layer, annotation

I am trying to render a CSV file as an annotation layer on QgsmapCanvas using QGIS3 C++ API.
but when I make a vector layer using "delimitedtext" as data provider and test **layer->isvalid()**. it says invalid.
Here is the piece of code:

```
QString uri = QString("file:///C:/Users/Puneet/Desktop/annotation/countries.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=latitude&yField=longitude");
qDebug()<< "URI :: " << uri;
QString baseName = QFileInfo(uri).completeBaseName();
qInfo()<< "annotation layer basename::"<< baseName;
QgsVectorLayer *layer = new QgsVectorLayer(uri, "countries", "delimitedtext");
qDebug()<< " annotation layer validity" << layer->isValid();   // returns false.
```

Here is the image of CSV file.
[image]

How can I fix this?  What am I missing?

Comment: Do not directly know but look at this code in QGIS cpp tests to find out https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/analysis/testqgsprocessing.cpp#L11224 Also not sure when you speak about "annotation layer" if it's about `QgsVectorLayer` or `QgsAnnotation` children like `QgsTextAnnotation` (Python sample at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282854/programmatically-adding-annotations). In QGIS, there annotation objects or layers objects, hence my question.

Comment: in my case. CSV file will contain lat/long and country names. I need to make a layer using this CSV file and render this on Qgsmapcanvas. in QgsMapCanvas will show these positions using some tiny points or symbols.

Comment: Loading header with `#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>` and trying `qDebug(QgsProviderRegistry::instance()->providerList().join(",").toUtf8().constData());`, what is your ouptut? Mine is `DB2,OAPIF,WFS,arcgisfeatureserver,arcgismapserver,delimitedtext,gdal,geonode,gpx,mdal,memory,mesh_memory,mssql,ogr,ows,postgres,postgresraster,spatialite,vectortile,virtual,wcs,wms`

Comment: mine is 
data providers::  ("gdal", "memory", "mesh_memory", "ogr", "vectortile")
how would I add "delimitedtext"  in my system ? I  was using OSGEO4W package.I had included 7 libraries(qgis_3d.lib, qgis_analysis.lib, qgis_app.lib ,qgis_core.lib,  qgis_gui.lib , qgis_native.lib, qgis_server.lib ) for various work. what should I do to include extra data provides and where can I find them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is elsewhere. You do not load all providers and in this case `delimitedtext`

Because provider is not available, your code always fails.

You need to declare something like that at the beginning

```cpp
// At the top add
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>

// Later on
// Directory mentioned in myPluginsDir should contained various dll including delimitedtextprovider.dll (on windows)
QString myPluginsDir = "C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/apps/qgis/plugins/"
QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);
# To see if providers list has changed
qDebug(QgsProviderRegistry::instance()->providerList().join(",").toUtf8().constData());
// Should contains something like DB2,OAPIF,WFS,arcgisfeatureserver,arcgismapserver,delimitedtext,gdal,geonode,gpx,mdal,memory,mesh_memory,mssql,ogr,ows,postgres,postgresraster,spatialite,vectortile,virtual,wcs,wms
// If issue with providers loading or not not loaded, you should only have a shorter list like gdal,memory,mesh_memory,ogr,vectortile
```

With the correction, you should now get your CSV layer loading.

Comment: thanks for taking interest. 
I tried but still, it is not updating data providers. but plugin folder contains all the dlls.
I tried QgsApplication::setPluginPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\plugins");and checked plugin path using pluginPath() method.  it is showing "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis/plugin". I think it should be "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\plugin". then It should provide all dlls. but it is not happening

Comment: Tested on Linux, got the same initial issue. With above, was able to solve the issue you got. Don't know why not working on Windows

Comment: My code is in this branch https://github.com/ThomasG77/QGIS-Code-Examples/tree/sample-vector-layer/6_accessing_vector_attributes PS: some hard coded path and paths for Linux

Comment: I added delimitedtext provider. After that, I made csvprovideString as you did in your GitHub branch and tested its validity. But  It is saying FALSE.
Here is the csvpriderString="file://C:/Users/Puneet/Desktop/annotation/countries.csv?type=csv&encoding=UTF-8&useHeader=Yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&geomType=point&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"
what is going wrong in this ?

Comment: You may need a QString not a String e.g the doc https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1e7827a9d7bd33549babdc3bd7a279fd so, should be `QString csvProviderString = QString("file://C:/Users/Puneet/Desktop/annotation/countries.csv?type=csv&encoding=UTF-8&useHeader=Yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&geomType=point&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no");`

Comment: You may also debug within PyQGIS to be sure the path is OK by opening the QGIS Python console and trying `csvProviderString = "file://C:/Users/Puneet/Desktop/annotation/countries.csv?type=csv&encoding=UTF-8&useHeader=Yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&geomType=point&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no";csvLayer = QgsVectorLayer(csvProviderString, "vl", "delimitedtext");print(csvLayer.isValid());`

Comment: I tried this on the python console in qgis 3.16 application. It is giving FALSE but when I render it as vector layer(delimited text). It gets renderd. My Python code: uri ="file://C:/Users/Puneet/Desktop/annotation/countries.csv?delimiter=,&xField=latitude&yField=longitude"; vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "v1", "delimitedtext"); vlayer.isValid() What is going wrong in this ?

Comment: I tried both types of python code. but Everyone is giving false.

Comment: the path is ok. because It printed the content of the CSV file using the same path